# Permutations don't affect summation in complex series implies absolute convergence?

Tags: calculus, analysis, complex-analysis

Let $\sum a_{n}$ be a complex series that converges. Now let $\sum a'_{n}$ be a rearrangement of that series. If we have
$$
\sum a_{n}=\sum a'_{n}
$$
for all rearrangements, is it true that $\sum a_{n}$ converges absolutely?

On a similar note, for all of you who own Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, can you check if there is a Theorem 3.56 in your book? Rudin cites it in Real and Complex Analysis, and I can't tell if it's a typo or was the theorem added in later printings.

Comment: In my edition this theorem is presented for real-valued series. But it can be easily generalized to complex-valued series.

Comment: Neither of my copies of Rudin have a theorem 3.56, but Rudin does have two texts, one with a blue cover that only does real analysis and one with a green cover that does both complex and real analysis. Are you sure you're checking the right one? I only have access to the blue book.

Comment: I think this is a typo in papa Rudin, as is refers to Theorem 3.56 in baby Rudin (3rd Ed.), which does not exist. Maybe it exists in another edition of baby Rudin, and was later removed, and Rudin forgot about the removal?

Comment: If one has already proven the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Riemann_series_theorem) (RRT), the above claim for reals follows immediately from the contrapositive of RRT. For $a_n$ complex, RRT similarly shows that $\operatorname{Re}(a_n)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(a_n)$ converge absolutely, hence so does $a_n$ because $|a_n| \leq |\operatorname{Re}(a_n)| + |\operatorname{Im}(a_n)|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true.  Suppose $\sum a_n$ does not converge absolutely, i.e. $\sum |a_n| = +\infty$.  Write $a_n = b_n - c_n + i d_n - i e_n$ where $b_n = \max(\text{Re}(a_n),0)$,
$c_n = \max(-\text{Re}(a_n),0)$, $d_n = \max(\text{Im}(a_n),0)$, $e_n = \max(-\text{Im}(a_n),0)$ are all nonnegative.  Since $|a_n| \le b_n + c_n + d_n + e_n$, at least one of
$\sum b_n$, $\sum c_n$, $\sum d_n$, $\sum e_n$ is $+\infty$.  Let's say it is $\sum b_n$.
Let $A$ be the set of positive integers $n$ for which $b_n > 0$ (i.e. $\text{Re}(a_n) > 0$), and $B$ those for which $\text{Re}(a_n) \le 0$.  Split up $A$ into infinitely many disjoint finite blocks $A_1, A_2, \ldots$, so that $\sum_{n \in A_k} \text{Re}(a_n) \ge 1$.  Then rearrange the series as follows: take $a_n$ for $n \in A_1$, then the first member of $B$, then $A_2$, then the second member of $B$, etc.  The rearranged series diverges, because summing over a block $A_k$ always changes the partial sum by at least $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your response.